# Block windows UI

Tags: .net, windows

I'm trying to build a simple app for parenting control in .NET. The main idea is to force a certain user account to run my app and to block all access to windows desktop UI. Anyone know how can i achieve this or where should i start researching? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for this for a while and just found what seems to be a great example of something similar to what you might be trying to achieve. The well-known programming blogger [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/) wrote his [BabySmash!](http://babysmash.codeplex.com/) program and hosted it over at CodePlex. It may not be exactly what you want, but looking at the methods he uses to block interaction with the OS/other programs outside your own might give you some ideas.

Description from the CodePlex page:

> As babies smash on the keyboard,
>   colored shapes, letters and numbers
>   appear on the screen. Baby Smash will
>   lock out the Windows Key, as well as
>   Ctrl-Esc and Alt-Tab so your baby
>   can't get out of the application.
>   Pressing ALT-F4 will exit the
>   application and Shift-Ctrl-Alt-O
>   brings up the options dialog.
>
> I wrote BabySmash! for my 2 year old
>   and 5 month old so they could bang on
>   the keyboards of my Windows machines
>   without hurting anything. It's a
>   copy/homage of the very fine and free
>   AlphaBaby for the Macintosh. BabySmash
>   is free also and I'll release the
>   source code on my blog soon. Enjoy.

Comment: Also a StackOverflow user, I shouldn't neglect to point out! http://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a shell replacement.  You need to start by setting the shell to an app that will choose Explorer or your program based on the user logging in.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell_replacement